# MAMP Pro problems launching SQL Server after system clean

Tags: mysql, apache, wordpress, mamp

I've been building a Wordpress Multiuser site for the last two months. Everything was good:

- Had a local configuration saved in MAMP using default ports (was FTP accessible) Which means I had to edit etc/host and point to site root on drive
- Had it saved MAMP's folder structure
- Could toggle between default ports and MAMP ports for other sites in development

After the cleaning, MAMP Pro would crash at firing up the SQL Server.

I was able to fix the crash by going into terminal and modifying a line. The last line had my IP address and `null` just after it. So once I added `wordpress.mu`, or `localhost`, the server would start.

But to no avail. I can't seem to recall the configuration after I've tampered with my MAMP settings.

- I believe I set an alias and named one of the hosts as wordpress.mu.
- I had MAMP pointing to a folder with a different title.
- The alias was local host.

And (when testing the site), I would type: `localhost.localdomain/sitetitle`. This is no longer working.

Can someone point me to thorough instructions or shoot me a few tips on what I should check on? While it might be an easy fix (at least I'm hoping) it's gotten a bit over my head as I am just exhausted from researching possible solutions to problems I semi-understand.

Thanks in advance community, pals, and web scientists. I'd love to treat whomever helps me successfully to a starbucks card. :)

Comment: Really nice edits Jon. It was late when I posted. Even so, you've made it a more useful post. Hope I find an answer soon.

Comment: Going to a solution I found on Wordpress Answers: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/32779/11485. I'll let you guys know how it works out when I try it this evening.

Comment: This is tagged "mysql", but still you keep saying "SQL Server". Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using the Pro version, so I may a little off base here, but I'd check the following..

Does the MAMP homepage work? (http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English)

Do you need to edit Apache's config? (httpd.conf) You might not need to when using MAMP Pro.

Is MySQL failing to start because there's already an instance running (look for a process called mysqld in Activity Monitor)?

Do you have a hosts entry for localhost.localdomain pointing to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: That should be a comment. It's not an answer

Comment: Pretty sure the question said "Can someone point me to thorough instructions or shoot me a few tips on what I should check on? " But hey..